# Java Translating From English to Pig Latin

Tags: java

I have an assignment for a computer science class to take in a word in english, and reprint it in pig latin (in this case, simply take the first letter and put it at the end). This is my code. Note: for full credit, it must be 2 different methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PigLatin {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string in english: ");
    String x = kboard.nextLine();


}

public static void pLatin(String x){
    String pigx = x.substring(0,1);
    String pigy = x.substring(1);
    System.out.println("The string in pig latin is " + pigy + pigx);


    }

}
```

I get no errors in Eclipse, but when I run the program, it does not print anything after I type in the word for the scanner. what am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Did you forget to call the `pLatin` method?

Comment: Do you call `pLatin` somewhere?

Comment: You have declared a method called `pLatin()`, but you never call it. To get you started: `pLatin(x);` after `String x = kboard.nextLine();`.

Comment: `main` is called automatically upon program start. In main you must call `pLatin`. The parameter name `x` has no relation whatsoever with the local variable `x`.

Comment: I do not think so, but if I did, how do i go about calling it?

Comment: It's worth getting into the habit of giving your variables sensible names. `String line = kboard.nextLine()`

Comment: ah, never mind, I got it. thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

You never tell it to print the word, nor to call your `pLatin()` function for that matter.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string in english: ");
    String x = kboard.nextLine();
    // MISSING: System.out.println("recieved: " + x);
    // MISSING: pLatin(x);
}
```

Also I don't think your `pLatin` function makes correct pig latin.

Answer (score 0):

Add this call of your method in the public static void main...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string in english: ");
        String x = kboard.nextLine();

        pLatin(x);

}
```

...and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string in english: ");
    System.out.println("The string in pig latin is: "+ pLatin(kboard.nextLine())); 
}

public static String  pLatin(String x){
    return x+x.charAt(0);
}
```

one problem is:

```
    String pigx = x.substring(0,1); //pigx = the first two letters
                                    //if the world is java -> pigx=ja
    String pigy = x.substring(1); //pigy= all the letters except the first 
                                  //letter. if world is java-> pigy= ava 

    System.out.println("The string in pig latin is " + pigy + pigx);
```

by this code you are not adding the first letter to the last index of a world,
you are getting and printing the first two letters(pigx) and all the letters except the first letter(pigy).